# Generate a class based on a database query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, ef-database-first

I need to create a model based on a number of MS Access queries. I see a lot of discussion on building classes from tables but nothing about queries. Maybe I’m looking at this wrong.

I am not familiar with lambda and linq yet but I’m open to ideas that help me get moving.